# Difference between ${} and $() in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have two questions and could use some help understanding them.

1. What is the difference between `${}` and `$()`? I understand that `()`
   means running command in separate shell and placing `$` means passing
   the value to variable. Can someone help me in understanding
   this? Please correct me if I am wrong.
2. If we can use `for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; done` and it works fine then why can't I use it as `while ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; done`? What is the difference in execution cycle for both?

Comment: It is a 2 part question. "Backticks vs. braces" just happens to have answers for both? If it answers 1, ask OP to edit it so that it is a standard, singular question.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The syntax is token-level, so the meaning of the dollar sign depends on the token it's in. The expression `$(command)` is a modern synonym for `` `command` `` which stands for command substitution; it means run `command` and put its output here. So

```
echo "Today is $(date). A fine day."
```

will run the `date` command and include its output in the argument to `echo`. The parentheses are unrelated to the syntax for running a command in a subshell, although they have something in common (the command substitution also runs in a separate subshell).

By contrast, `${variable}` is just a disambiguation mechanism, so you can say `${var}text` when you mean the contents of the variable `var`, followed by `text` (as opposed to `$vartext` which means the contents of the variable `vartext`).

The `while` loop expects a single argument which should evaluate to true or false (or actually multiple, where the last one's truth value is examined -- thanks Jonathan Leffler for pointing this out); when it's false, the loop is no longer executed. The `for` loop iterates over a list of items and binds each to a loop variable in turn; the syntax you refer to is one (rather generalized) way to express a loop over a range of arithmetic values.

A `for` loop like that can be rephrased as a `while` loop. The expression

```
for ((init; check; step)); do
    body
done
```

is equivalent to

```
init
while check; do
    body
    step
done
```

It makes sense to keep all the loop control in one place for legibility; but as you can see when it's expressed like this, the `for` loop does quite a bit more than the `while` loop.

Of course, this syntax is Bash-specific; classic Bourne shell only has

```
for variable in token1 token2 ...; do
```

---

(Somewhat more elegantly, you could avoid the `echo` in the first example as long as you are sure that your argument string doesn't contain any `%` format codes:

```
date +'Today is %c. A fine day.'
```

Avoiding a process where you can is an important consideration, even though it doesn't make a lot of difference in this isolated example.)

Comment: Strictly, a `while` command expects a sequence of commands (not necessarily a pipeline), and the exit status of the last command in the sequence determines whether the loop continues or not.  Thus: `while ls; pwd; date; do echo Hi; sleep 1; done` is valid, and the exit status of `date` controls whether the loop continues or not.  I used semicolons because you can't format newlines in a comment, but you could write the commands on multiple lines in a shell script.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted that this answer continues to receive upvotes; it's not particularly stellar. If you upvoted this, would you care to explain which part of it is useful? I guess the relationship between `for` loops and `while` loops isn't entirely obvious (I remember liking it when I first read it in on the first edition of the Perl *Camel Book)* but is there anything other than that ...?

Comment: There's also the issue of 'well, the other two answers are not better'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Heh, maybe just abstain from voting then (-:

Comment: @tripleee Why don't you want the upvotes? Anyway I often upvote answers because if they are helpful (in this case I needed to know the difference between $() and ${}) regardless of whether they are _stellar_...

Comment: @BenJones Thanks for following up! I don't particularly mind the upvotes per se, I'm just baffled if this is a common question for people to have, or if this post on Stack Overflow is the one they are drawn to for an answer. (But I guess the title helps, and the distraction with a second unrelated question in the same post is easy to ignore, even if it's still a distraction.)

Answer (score 103):

1. `$()` means: "first evaluate this, and then evaluate the rest of the line".

   Ex :

   ```
   echo $(pwd)/myFile.txt
   ```

   will be interpreted as

   ```
   echo /my/path/myFile.txt
   ```

   On the other hand `${}` expands a variable.

   Ex:

   ```
   MY_VAR=toto
   echo ${MY_VAR}/myFile.txt
   ```

   will be interpreted as

   ```
   echo toto/myFile.txt
   ```
2. > Why can't I use it as `bash$ while ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; done`

   I'm afraid the answer is just that the bash syntax for `while` just isn't the same as the syntax for `for`.

Comment: "first evaluate this, and then evaluate the rest of the line" -- I don't understand this description of `$(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

1. your understanding is right. For detailed info on {} see [bash ref - parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
2. 'for' and 'while' have different syntax and offer different styles of programmer control for an iteration. Most non-asm languages offer a similar syntax.

With while, you would probably write `i=0; while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do echo $i; i=$(( i + 1 )); done` in essence manage everything about the iteration yourself

Comment: Not my down-vote, but the OP seems to be confusing `(command …)` with `$(commnd …)`, which are quite different in detail, though they share some commonality too.  Thus, your first observation is not entirely accurate; the OP's understanding is not entirely correct.

Comment: _Most non-asm languages offer a similar syntax._ What???

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf FOR syntax. In most non-assembly languages (in my limited knowledge), not counting some ancient ones like algol

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for clarifying. I too thought so but figured that in the context OP had not meant a subshell.