# How do I restart all docker containers with a pause between each restart?

Tags: bash, docker, sleep, restart

I'd like to put a pause (maybe just `sleep` somehow?) in this one liner in between each `restart` because there's quite a few containers on this server and having it slow down the restarts will mean less of a load spike. If possible, I'd like to keep this a one liner, and avoid putting this into a bash shell script file. I know how to put a `sleep` into a for loop in a bash script, but I don't know how to put it into this. What's the `$()` part called?

```
docker restart $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep -v somename)
```

So I'm just wanting to make a list of running containers, and restart each one with maybe a 30 second pause in between each restart.

Comment: `$(...)` syntax is [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), according to POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `$()` as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472540/difference-between-and-in-bash) is:

> The syntax is token-level, so the meaning of the dollar sign depends on the token it's in. The expression $(command) is a modern synonym for `command` which stands for command substitution; it means, run command and put its output here.

What you need to perform all the restarts followed by a pause is a loop over the lines in the `$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep -v somename)"` command, and inside the loop, do a `docker restart $line` and then a `sleep 30` (for 30 seconds) command.

Something like this:

```
items=$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep -v somename)
for word in $items
do
    docker restart $word
    sleep 30
done
```

---

### Explanation:

```
items=$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep -v somename)
```

This line sets a string variable named `items` that contains all the names of containers separated by spaces, as you did in your original command.

```
for word in $items
```

automatically splits the string by spaces, giving you a different container name in every iteration of the `for` loop.

Between

```
do
```

and

```
done
```

we have the code that is executed with each of the words in the `items` string, which is the following

```
    docker restart $word
```

We restart the docker container as you did, but only for one of the containers, its name read from `$word`.

```
    sleep 30
```

We sleep for 30 seconds before iterating again over the next `$word` value.

---

### Single line version

If you want a compact version that you can run as a single line, you can do:

```
items=$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep -v somename);for word in $items; do;  docker restart $word; sleep 30; done;
```