# How to kill the port node env is using

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, port

I am collaborating on a deploy using `sudo` with ssh access to aws ec2 instance.

The application starts up and throws the error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4000
```

---

*if I do:*

```
sudo fuser 4000/tcp
```

*I get:*

```
4000/tcp:             1669
```

---

*If I do:*

```
sudo fuser -i -k 4000/tcp
```

*I get:*

```
4000/tcp:             1669 Kill process 1669 ? (y/N)
```

---

*If I do:*

```
y
```

It doesn't kill the port. I have stopped the app as well of course.

---

I don't have netstat.

Is this a privilege thing with the root access? I would try to change the port number but don't have that access right now.

Is there anything else I can try?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a combination of kill and lsof.

`sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:4000)`

Which tells the os to terminate the process using port 4000.

- `sudo` You're likely going to need root level access
- `kill -9` [tells the os to terminate the process](https://askubuntu.com/a/184231)
- `$(some command)` command substitution
  / [run the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472808/2110294)
- `lsof -t` implies [terse output excluding
  headers](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)
- `lsof -i:PORT_NUMBER` is used to [filter the list by internet
  address](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)/port

Comment: If I do that above command and then run `lsof -i:4000` it outputs that the port is still running with **COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node\x20/ 21387 pavlos   19u  IPv6 102232168      0t0  TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)**

Comment: Now when I do `sudo kill -9 PID_NUM`  it just finds another PID to open. This is mad.

Comment: Any ideas @Craig ?

Comment: @godhar What os, do you use something like forever to keep the process up? The ls command should output the pid of the process which uses that port, if it reopens when killed, how did you start the process?

Comment: it turns out the other user kept running the app on the linux machine. I was trying to kill the process then it would must find another PID. Interesting that often the solution is the most obvious one. thanks