# Whats The Correct Syntax to input the Own IP into an SED Command

Tags: bash

```
sed -i 's/# ListenIP=0.0.0.0/ListenIP=$[hostname -I]' /etc/some.conf
```

I need to Change the Listen Ip to its own IP, so what's the correct way of inserting `hostname -I` into the SED command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command substitution [`$()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472808/5625547) to call a subshell:

```sh
sed -i "s/# ListenIP=0.0.0.0/ListenIP=$(hostname -I)/" /etc/some.conf
```

Comment: That's what I thought but it didn't work, but I wrote it with ' instead of " so that was my problem. Thanks.