# curl command in command substitution prints spurious progress indicator

Tags: bash, curl

```
curl -SX POST http://127.0.0.1/open/api/pudao/fileupload
: $(curl -SX POST http://127.0.0.1/open/api/pudao/fileupload)
```

(The command substitution is not useful here as such, it's just a minimal reproducible example.)

In the latter case, I see a progress indicator like

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 after 8 ms: Connection refused
```

[image]

Why does the same command produce different output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between ${} and $() in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472540/difference-between-and-in-bash)

Comment: The actual answer to the question is probably that `curl` behaves slightly differently when its output is not to a terminal. But we are at loss as to why you would expect to run the empty output as a command.

Comment: I can concur that this behavior is unexpected and probably a bug. As such, we have a number of questions about why some utilities like `git` and `top` behave differently when used interactively; I'm tempted to vote to close as a duplicate of one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isatty` is used in the `curl` source code; the `isatty()` function returns 0 in a command subtitution `$()`. It will happen again when you redirect stdout to elsewhere without a tty. I think is the real reason.